# Mal calculo de maximos (codigo de las 10 ciudades con mas cantidad de clientes). En pascal

Tags: pascal, vectores

Estoy teniendo inconveniente al momento de calcular los codigos de las 10 ciudades con mayor cantidad de clientes. (SOLO DEBO UTILIZAR VECTORES)

En este programa utilizo varios vectores.
vClientes: almaceno la informacion de los clientes.
vContadorCategorias: almaceno la cantidad de clientes por categoria.
vClientesCiudad: cuento la cantidad de clientes por ciudad, y el codigo de ciudad.

Para resolver el inciso c ( codigo de las 10 ciudades con mayor cantidad de clientes )
Lo plantee de esta forma:
Use el vector vClientesCiudad para ir contando la cantidad de clientes por ciudad (este vector va de 1 hasta cantCiudades (2400)).

Para sacar el maximo, mi idea es ordenar el vector vClientesCiudad por cantidad de clientes de mayor a menor. Es lo que hice. Pero al momento de informarme los 10 codigos me informa todo con codigo 0.

Por favor, llevo vario tiempo sin poder solucionarlo. Me parecio la manera mas facil de plantearlo. Cualquier ayuda, consejo, o si lo plantearon diferente comenten que estoy atento.

Dejo el codigo. Los procesos importantes son: OrdenarVector e InformarTop10

```
{
program eje5prac4p2; 
const 
    cantClientes = 3; {puse 5 para hacer la prueba. Hay que poner 500}
    cantCiudades = 2400; 
type 
    rangoMeses = 1..12; 
    rangoDias = 1..31; 
    rangoCategoria = 'A'..'F'; 
    rangoCiudad = 1..2400;  
    
    fecha = record 
        mes : rangoMeses; 
        dia : rangoDias; 
        anho : integer; 
    end; 

    cliente = record 
        firmaContrato : fecha; 
        categoria : rangoCategoria; 
        ciudad : rangoCiudad; 
        monto : real;                         
    end; 

    vClientes  = array [1..cantClientes] of cliente; 

    vContadorCategorias = array ['A'..'F'] of integer; {debo inicializarlo en 0}


        mas_cobran = record 
            codCiudad : rangoCiudad; 
            cantClientes : integer; 
        end; 



    vClientesCiudad = array [1..cantCiudades] of mas_cobran; 
    {inicializo el vector.cantClientes en 0}
    {inicializo el vector.codCiudad en i (porque recorro en un for de 1 hasta 2400)}
    
     
    {ordeno el vector de manera ascendente por cantCLientes,
     e imprimo los primeros 10 de ese vector }
    procedure inicializarV_clientesCiudad (var v : vClientesCiudad); 
    var 
        i : integer; 
    begin
        for i:= 1 to cantCiudades do 
            v[i].cantClientes:= 0; 
            v[i].codCiudad:= i; 
    end;    

procedure ordenarVector  (  var v: vClientesCiudad) ; 
    var 
        i, j , p : integer; 
        aux : mas_cobran; 
    begin 
            for i:= 1 to (cantCiudades -1) do 
                p:= i ; 
                    for j := ( i+ 1) to cantCiudades do 
                        begin
                                if ( v[j].cantClientes > v[i].cantClientes) then 
                                    p:= j; 
                            
                            aux:= v[p]; 
                            v[p]:= v[i]; 
                            v[i]:= aux;
                        end;
    end; 

procedure informarTop10 (var v : vClientesCiudad); 
var 
    i : integer; 
begin 
        ordenarVector(v); 
         for i:= 1 to 10 do 
            begin 
                    writeln (i,':  con codigo de ciudad: ',v[i].codCiudad); 
            end; 
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pascal no es python.

No he verificado si el código hace lo que esperas que haga, pero si puedo observar, por la forma que estás indentando, cual es tu intención, sin embargo, has olvidado poner algún par de `begin/end`.

Por ejemplo aquí:

```
for i:= 1 to (cantCiudades -1) do 
  p:= i ; 
    for j := ( i+ 1) to cantCiudades do 
    begin
      ....
```

Entiendo que tu intención es que el segundo for esté anidado dentro del primero, pero no lo está. Por lo mismo, el primer for simplemente irá aumentando el valor de la variable `i` y, con ella, de la variable `p` sin hacer nada más, hasta llegar a `cantCiudades - 1`, o sea, 2399.

Hasta entonces se iniciará la ejecución del segundo ciclo `for`, que hará una única iteración, pues empieza en `i+1`, o sea 2400 y termina en `cantCiudades`, que también es 2400.

Está por demás decir que hubieras podido observar este comportamiento si hubieses ejecutado tu código paso a paso al menos una vez, pero es evidente que no lo has hecho, por lo que sugiero que aprendas a utilizar el depurador de tu entorno de desarrollo.

Por otro lado, si usas un compilador moderno de pascal, debió emitir un warning también al usar la variable `i` fuera del ciclo `for` anterior.

Finalmente, aplaudo que indentes el código, lo hace mucho más legible, pero te recomiendo seguir un estilo estándar para hacerlo, eso ayuda aún mucho más a su legibilidad.

Yo, por ejemplo, utilizo *saltos* de 2 caracteres, y el código siempre lleva espacios, nunca tabuladores (los IDE's de pascal usualmente vienen configurados así por defecto).

Considero que así, tu código, es más legible. Entiendo que yo tengo años de práctica y seguro eso me ayuda, pero mantener el estándar hace que te acostumbres.

Este código es básicamente el mismo, solo he añadido los pares de `begin/end` que considero que faltaban y estandarizado la indentación:

```
program eje5prac4p2; 
const 
  cantClientes = 3; {puse 5 para hacer la prueba. Hay que poner 500}
  cantCiudades = 2400; 
type 
  rangoMeses = 1..12; 
  rangoDias = 1..31; 
  rangoCategoria = 'A'..'F'; 
  rangoCiudad = 1..2400;  
    
  fecha = record 
    mes: rangoMeses; 
    dia: rangoDias; 
    anho: integer; 
  end; 

  cliente = record 
    firmaContrato: fecha; 
    categoria: rangoCategoria; 
    ciudad: rangoCiudad; 
    monto: real;                         
  end; 

  vClientes = array [1..cantClientes] of cliente; 

  vContadorCategorias = array ['A'..'F'] of integer; {debo inicializarlo en 0}

  mas_cobran = record 
    codCiudad : rangoCiudad; 
    cantClientes : integer; 
  end; 

  vClientesCiudad = array [1..cantCiudades] of mas_cobran; 
  {inicializo el vector.cantClientes en 0}
  {inicializo el vector.codCiudad en i (porque recorro en un for de 1 hasta 2400)}
    
     
  {ordeno el vector de manera ascendente por cantCLientes,
   e imprimo los primeros 10 de ese vector }
procedure inicializarV_clientesCiudad (var v : vClientesCiudad); 
var 
  i: integer; 
begin
  for i:= 1 to cantCiudades do 
  begin
    v[i].cantClientes:= 0; 
    v[i].codCiudad:= i; 
  end;
end;    

procedure ordenarVector(var v: vClientesCiudad); 
var 
  i, j, p: integer; 
  aux: mas_cobran; 
begin 
  for i := 1 to (cantCiudades - 1) do 
  begin
    p := i; 
    for j := (i + 1) to cantCiudades do 
    begin
      if (v[j].cantClientes > v[i].cantClientes) then 
      begin
        p := j; 
        aux:= v[p]; 
        v[p]:= v[i]; 
        v[i]:= aux;
      end;
    end; 
  end;
end;

procedure informarTop10 (var v :vClientesCiudad); 
var 
  i: integer; 
begin 
  ordenarVector(v); 
  for i := 1 to 10 do 
  begin 
    WriteLn(i, ':  con codigo de ciudad: ', v[i].codCiudad); 
  end; 
end;
```

Al hacerlo, no pude evitar observar que usas una variable `p` en el procedimiento `ordenarVector` que considero que está de más, puedes hacer todo con `i` y `j` sin problemas.